# Python , trying to open a command

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd

I have simple python code took from here only.It is

```
import os
os.system("start /WAIT cmd /c {ping google.com -t }")
```

My intention is ,I have to open a command prompt and then have to ping Google. Program should stopped when I close command prompt.

But , while I am doing with above code command prompt appearing but auto-closing.

I am not understanding what I have to do because I am pretty new.

I am using Python 2.7.6 in Windows 7 64-Bit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `cmd /?`, there's no mention about braces.

```
C:\>cmd /?
Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
....
```

Remove braces that surround the ping command. Then it will works as you expected.

```
import os
os.system("start /WAIT cmd /c ping google.com -t")
```